# How to uninstall PHP 7.3 after build-from-source using Homebrew on Mac OS 11

Tags: php, homebrew, macos-catalina, apple-m1

I need to run a php application that was built on php 7.3. Now that php 7.3 is no longer supported, I was unable to install using homebrew without including the `--build-from-source` option. I went ahead and attempted to build php 7.3 from source While trying to install and I encountered an error that terminated the build process:

```
Generating phar.phar
PEAR package PHP_Archive not installed: generated phar will require PHP's phar extension be enabled.
make: *** [ext/phar/phar.phar] Bus error: 10
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I've researched the error and found that this may have to do with the fact that I am installing on a Mac with an Apple M1 chip. I'd like to uninstall it now, upgrade the application to a supported version of php, and then run it. I tried running `brew uninstall php` and then install home-brew's default php, but the binary that was created by the first attempt is taking precedence over the latter php 8.0 version I installed.

My question is, is deleting the binaries located at `/usr/bin/` enough to completely remove the unsupported version of php from my system? I searched the tar for an uninstall target but no luck.

I just want to clean it out of my system and start over. I don't imagine that there is a php 7.3 version that works with my Apple M1 chip.

Thanks much

Comment: Can you report it into homebrew-core issue repo https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues as well?

Comment: My only concern here is that there is a warning issued by homebrew letting users know that this can happen. Ultimately I gambled on this working so I don't think this is necessarily their fault.